# Laravel Query Scope to select User models without a date within a time range on a related model

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a query scope that will select all Users who are not on vacation today. The vacation time is kept as a date range on a separate model called `TimeOff`. The fields on the `TimeOff` model are `start_date` and `end_date`.

This is what I've been trying for my scopes:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Carbon\Carbon;

trait UserScopes
{
    /**
     * @param $query
     * @param $day
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function scopeWhereIsNotTimeOffOnDay($query, $day)
    {
        return $query->where(function ($query) use ($day) {
            $query->whereDoesntHave('timeOffs', function ($query) use ($day) {
                $query->whereDate('start_date', '<=', $day->toDateString())
                    ->whereDate('end_date', '>=', $day->toDateString());
            });
        });
    }

    /**
     * @param $query
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function scopeWhereIsNotTimeOffToday($query)
    {
        return $query->whereIsNotTimeOffOnDay(Carbon::today());
    }
}
```

To test I've been using the following in tinker:

```php
User::whereIsNotTimeOffToday()->first()->name;
```

The results returned do not match what I expect. The scope is returning people who have a related TimeOff model and today falls in the vacation date range.

So, in short, I want users to select all users who are not currently on vacation.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: apologies that is a typo. it is `whereDate` for both in my code.

Comment: So the way I would logically think of this as "Someone being off today" is if they have a record that has a start or end date between the start and end of today (since in my use cases timeoff can overflow a single day). That translates to `timeoff.start_date BETWEEN '2020-09-02 00:00:00' and '2020-09-02 23:59:59' OR timeoff.end_date BETWEEN  '2020-09-02 00:00:00' and '2020-09-02 23:59:59'`. Does that make sense? And "today" can be today, or a given range, like "the beginning of yesterday to the end of tomorrow", etc etc.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but how would that work for a time off range that lasts many days? e.g. `start_date = 2020-09-02`  --  `end_date = 2020-09-15`

Comment: Oh right, I see what you're saying (I was backwards) In that case, it would be `'2020-09-02 13:33:00' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date`. This all goes back to my original thought that you need to find the query that works directly on the `timeoff` table, and apply that to your scope :)

Comment: Scratch this. Sorry, turns out I was testing this with the wrong user account through the web interface and was expecting to see results from a different account. What I have in the question above is working. Just a total screw up on my end. Apologies.

Comment: Oh haha :) And no worries; it happens. Glad you got this working!